# Create a list of integer vectors

Tags: r, list, matrix, dataframe

let us say I want to create a list where each element is an integer vector.

Let us say I have,

```
a = c(1,2,3,4)
b = c(7,9,10,3)
d = c(90.2,43.1,54.2,12.3)
```

And I'd like a list where element 1 of the list is:
`c(1,7,90.2)`
Second element is,
`c(2,9,43.1)`,
The third element is,
`c(3,10,54.2)`,
and the 4th element is,
`c(4,3,12.3)`.

If I do,

```
my.list = list(a=a,b=b,d=d)
```

gives me the transpose of what I want.  Is there any direct way to achieve such goal?

I need to have a list because I want to use the mclapply function and that function only takes lists as input, or (if given dataframes) will coerce them to the non desired list structure.

Note that in my program this vectors are quite huge, 400 million entries or so.  I am looking for a very fast and efficient way to do this.  Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "transpose" of a list?  Do you want to store your data as columns?  If so, then, as @tcash suggested, you should use `data.frame`s (but skip the second `apply` step)

Comment: If you need to keep a distinction between integer and numeric (floating point) column vectors, then you must work with the list (or dataframe) as is, without transposing it. If this distinction is irrelevant, then you should work with a numeric matrix instead, and use the function `t()` to transpose it.

Comment: Hi thanks, Well I cannot work with a data.frame because later I will use mclapply and mclapply takes only lists as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kk<-Map(function(x,y,w) c(x,y,w),a,b,d)
> kk[1]
[[1]]
[1]  1.0  7.0 90.2
```

Or just :

```
 kk<-Map(`c`,a,b,d)
> kk[1]
[[1]]
[1]  1.0  7.0 90.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn your vectors into one `data.frame`:

```
adf<-data.frame(a=a, b=b, d=d)
```

Then use `apply` to turn each row into a list element:

```
apply(adf, 1, function(x) list(x))
```

Comment: thanks, is this efficient if my vectors are on the order of 500 million elements?

Comment: hi, I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about this.